# Unix Shell Flags

Tags: shell, unix, set

I came across `$-` and found that it  is used to determine the flags set for the shell.So I just did an `echo $-` and it gave me **ism** . Now  ***i*** is for interactive shell, ***m*** is for monitor mode but I dont know what **s** means.

Moreover I have sample script test.sh as below

`#!/bin/ksh`

`echo "Hi I am shell and I am about to figure out the flags set for me :-)"`

`echo $-`

When I execute the script like this-- `./test.sh` I am getting the flag as **h** but upon executing `sh -x test.sh`
 I am getting **xh** . I think this  **x** is coming from **sh -x** but I am not sure how and why.

I tried to google reagrding  the flags but found nothing *(maybe because my seach keyword is not proper).*

Any information on this will be helpful.Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: As an aside, using `sh` to run a `ksh` script is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Korn shell in your script, are you using that interactively as well?

```
man ksh
```

is your friend.

```
-      Options supplied to the shell on invocation or by the set
                 command.
```

Search for `Invocation`, the correct term for these settings is *options* (not flags).

So yes, the `x` is from the `set -x`.  This is a shortcut for `set -o xtrace`.  To see all those options, and their current settings, `set -o` (note that only a few have single character shortcuts).  Try

```
set --man
```

on the command-line (if you have a very old version of ksh, that won't work).

`-s` just means that commands come from `stdin`.

Comment: Thanks @cdarke for your reply.As suggested by you I used the `man ksh` and figured out the meaning of all the options.

Comment: Thanks @cdarke for your reply.As suggested by you I used the `man ksh` and figured out the meaning of  the option **h** ,it's for ** trackall**.`man ksh` gave detailed explanation of all the options available under `set -o` commands and the shortcuts for it.

Comment: my apologies for not upvoting your answer as I dont have that privilege yet..It requires minimum of 15 reputations I got only 1 :-)

Comment: @UnixNewbie:  that's OK.  It's not about points.  Glad to help.